# How do I invoke a Shell Script with a specific keyword? ie: "run foo"

Tags: shell

I'm trying to make a script that can be invoked in the following fashion:
"run foo"

The script will run with the command line argument foo. Can this even be done with a shell script? The best I can do is "sh run.sh foo". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Despite giving you an answer, it is pretty much guaranteed that this is a duplicate of another question.  It will take a lot longer to find that duplicate than it does to give the answer.  (The related question [How to make a file into a shell script and run it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412786/how-to-make-a-file-into-a-shell-script-and-run-it) is not a good duplicate; it's related, but the answers go down a different tack altogether.)

Comment: Incidentally, note that `run` is not a keyword.  It isn't entirely clear if you want the `run` command to run a script called `foo`, or if your script that is currently called `run.sh` should be made so that it can be invoked as `run` and given an argument `foo`.  My answer assumes the latter interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make the file `run` a copy of, or link to, your `run.sh` (or simply move `run.sh` to `run`).
- Make the file `run` executable (`chmod 755 run` or more restrictive, but the owner permissions must be at least 5).
- Make sure `run` is in a directory on your `PATH` (e.g. `$HOME/bin` if that is on your `PATH`; if you don't have `$HOME/bin` on your `PATH`, create the directory and add it to your `PATH` in your profile or other startup scripts).

Then you can type:

```
run foo
```

Note that if you want the script run with `/bin/sh`, make sure the first line of `run` is `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Name the script `run` and place it into a directory in $PATH. Also make sure it has executable permissions and shebang.

$PATH is a special variable that holds the path the shell will search when executing a command without path.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv run.sh /usr/local/bin/run
run foo
```

Comment: You've not explained what you're doing, and you've not made sure the script is executable (and I'm not entirely happy with the prospect of anyone being able to install software in `/usr/local/bin` either, but that's a security issue more than an issue of the basic techniques).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right, I forget to "chmod u+x run.sh" first. I just  found /usr/local/bin handy and everyone seems to have write access to it by default. Don't know why though.

Comment: It's handy all right, but I'd be worried about anyone being able to add commands to it.  Especially if anyone puts `/usr/local/bin` on their path ahead of `/bin` or `/usr/bin` and gets tricked into running some attacker's surrogate for `ls` that actually gives the attacker a shell that's SUID to the victim, for example.

Comment: You're allowed to fix issues like the missing `chmod` and I would probably then remove my comment(s).